# C#/ Html Agility pack error "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: Source."

Tags: c#-4.0, html-agility-pack

I've used html agility pack before, and have had good results with a little bit of trial and error. I'm currently trying to use it to return a node set with an xpath I get by right- clicking "Copy XPath" in Firefox. I've done some searching, and I see that the browser will often add "tbody" for table tags. I tried it with removing this with no luck. Here is the xpath given to me by Firefox:

```
/html/body/p[3]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]
```

Using it as- is throws the error: "*Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source.*"

This occurs on line:

```
nodeList = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/p[3]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]").ToList();
```

I'll continue to read, in the meantime if this is an easy fix to anyone, I'd appreciate a tip.

Update: This is the actual code:

```
protected override List<IDataPoint> ReturnDataPointsFromIndividualAddressString(string AddressString)
{
       List<IDataPoint> earningsAnnouncements = new List<IDataPoint>(); //Not used, yet..

       HtmlWeb hwObject = new HtmlWeb();
       HtmlDocument htmlDoc = hwObject.Load(AddressString);

       if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null)
       {
               List<HtmlNode> nodeList = new List<HtmlNode>();
               nodeList = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/p[3]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]").ToList();
       }
}
```

Comment: Could you post a code which causes this error?

Comment: Sure, I'll update original post..

Answer (score 7):

It seems this error occurs on this line:

```
nodeList = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/p[3]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]").ToList();
```

The thing is, if `SelectNodes` method doesn't find nodes by xpath expression passed it returns `null`. You could find more information in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5802547/102112) to a similar question *HTML Agility Pack Null Reference*. And then you call a `ToList()` method on a `null` object which is actually causes an `NullReferenceException`.

To avoid this check the this variable against `null` like this:

```
var nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(...);
if (nodes != null)
{
     nodeList = nodes.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Actually the error occurs on: HtmlDocument htmlDoc = hwObject.Load(AddressString);

Comment: @StatsViaCs, it's strange. I can't see how`HtmlWeb.Load` throws an `NullReferenceException` with the `source` parameter. Could you post the value of `AddressString` which caused this error?

Comment: My mistake Alex.. it does indeed throw it on the line you suggested, I had stepped away for a bit, sorry.

Comment: You're right, that is indeed null, so I'll use your method to avoid the exception in the future. I guess my question is what is wrong with my xpath?

Comment: @StatsViaCsh, it depends on the HTML source, and on what nodes are you trying to find