# null value exception for a list in a winform

Tags: c#, winforms, arraylist, html-agility-pack

I have 2 lists:

```
public List<string> my_link = new List<string>();
public List<string> english_word = new List<string>();
```

I am scraping some links from a page and save them onto "my_link";for this I am using these codes like:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://search.freefind.com/find.html?id=59478474&pid=r&ics=1&query=" + x);
HtmlNodeCollection nodes=doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//font[@class='search-results']//a");

try
{
    foreach (HtmlNode n in nodes)
    {
        link = n.InnerHtml;
        link = link.Trim();
        my_link.Add(link);
    }
}
catch (NullReferenceException )
{
    MessageBox.Show("NO link found ");            
}
```

Then i am scraping  some content going on that links which I scrapped and I stored that content of each link on a `english_word.Add(q);` It can scrape content from  all links except the last one.my code is like that

```
foreach (string ss in my_link)
{
    HtmlWeb web2 = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc2 = web2.Load(ss);
    HtmlNodeCollection nodes2 = doc2.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id='table1']//tr[position()>1]//td[position()=2]");
    try
    {
        foreach (HtmlNode nn in nodes2)
        {
            q = nn.InnerText;
            q = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(q);
            q = q.Trim();
            english_word.Add(q);
        }
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No english word is found ");
    }
}
```

For last link only it shows "No english word is found "

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Catching NullReferenceException is rarely the right thing to do.

Comment: If you don't ignore the actual exception, you might be able to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Agreed! Instead check for null! `if (object != null)` or `if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(yourString))` for strings.

Comment: Where can  i use this on my code???@Amicable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, catching a `NullReferenceException` here is not a very good idea. It's better to check for `null` where you're expecting nulls.

Second, most probably you get this exception because of `HtmlNode.SelectNodes` method returns `null` (not an empty collection of nodes, as you've been expected) if no nodes found. See HTML [Agility Pack Null Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5802547/102112), [C#/ Html Agility pack error “Value cannot be null. Parameter name: Source.”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10000565/102112), and a discussion on [CodePlex](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/workitem/29175).

So, instead of a `try .. catch` block you could use something like:

```
if (nodes2 != null)
{
    foreach (HtmlNode nn in nodes2)
    {
        q = nn.InnerText;
        q = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(q);
        q = q.Trim();
        english_word.Add(q);
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("No english word is found ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your catch statement to catch all exceptions, not just NullReferenceException.
2. Debugger is your friend, use it. I'm guessing that you get exception somewhere before adding a new word to the list. Set a breakpoint in your foreach loop.